# Email multiple contacts in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email to multiple addresses. The code below shows what I'm attempting to achieve. When I add two addresses the email does not send to the second address. The code is:

```
   me = 'a@a.com'
   you = 'a@a.com, a@a.com'
   msg['Subject'] = "Some Subject"
   msg['From'] = me
   msg['To'] = you

   # Send the message via our own SMTP server
   s = smtplib.SMTP('a.a.a.a')
   s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
   s.quit()
```

I have tried:

```
you = ['a@a.com', 'a@a.com']
```

and

```
you = 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com'
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried 'a@a.com; a@a.com' ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
s.sendmail(me, you.split(","), msg.as_string())
```

If you do `you = ['a@a.com', 'a@a.com']`

Try

```
msg['To'] = ",".join(you)

...

s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 14):

You want this:

```
from email.utils import COMMASPACE
...
you = ["foo@example.com", "bar@example.com"]
...
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(you)
...
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
you = ('one@address', 'another@address')
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.foobar.com')
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = 'me@mail.com'
recipients = ['foo@mail.com', 'bar@mail.com']
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

---

In the example to read emails from the configuration file, for example [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) - `pip install configparser`.

- In the created `config.ini` file we add the code from below:

```
[mail]
SENDER    = me@mail.com
RECEIVERS = foo@mail.com,bar@mail.com
```

- Create another `test.py` file located in the same directory

```py
import configparser
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException

config  = configparser.RawConfigParser() 
config.read('config.ini')

# template
msg = """From: From Person <{0}>
To:{1}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: Hello {2}

Check your results :)

{3}
"""

# universal function that would send mail when called
def send_mail(sender, receivers, subject, message):
    try:
        session = smtplib.SMTP(host = "ip", port = 25)
        session.ehlo()
        session.starttls()
        session.ehlo()
        session.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.format(sender, receivers, subject, message)) 
        session.quit()
        print("Your mail has been sent successfuly! Thank you for your feedback!")
    except SMTPException:
        print("Error: Unable to send email.")

# html context for email
your_subject = "SMTP HTML e-mail test"
your_message = """This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format
<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
"""

# The call to the universal e-mail function to which we pass the parameters in this example are given above
def setup_and_send_mail():
    send_mail(config.get('mail', 'SENDER'), (config.get('mail', 'RECEIVERS')), your_subject, your_message) 


if __name__ == "__main__":

    setup_and_send_mail()
```